# Dynamically added other tags does not save in database

Tags: jquery, moodle

I customize a jquery tag editor [plug-in](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2011/09/09/tag-editor-field-using-jquery-similar-to-stackoverflow) for moodle.
So it dynamically add a input box under the moodle question's tag field.
And when i add any text in it, it dynamically added to other tags-(a text area).

Finally when i click on save change button it not saved.
On the other hand when i write directly on other tags (text-area) then it works perfectly.

any guess??

Here is my code for text append or remove

```
function jQ_append(id_of_input, text){
  $(id_of_input).val($(id_of_input).val() + text + ",");
}    
function jQ_remove(id_of_input,text){
  var string = $(id_of_input).val();
  text=text + ",";
  str = string.replace(text, "");
  $(id_of_input).val(str);  
}
```

Comment: before saving $("#yourelement").trigger('create');

Comment: where is you related code... please post it so that we can have some idea